# passwordless ssh login but su password does not work

Tags: passwords, ssh, rsa, putty

I can use RSA keys to putty into my centos VPS with no problem. But it has been a long time since I used that system. So putty-ed in with the intention of updating it, and when I tried 'su' my password didn't work. I had disabled password login for ssh but that shouldn't affect me running su commands while I'm in an ssh session... right?

Comment: This is more of a [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) question.  The answer is no, though.

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116529/i-cant-login-as-root-with-su-command-but-i-can-with-ssh)?